# Some problems with Checkbox. I can't create a checkbox. (asp.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

The purpose of the app is to add a price to an offer and choose one or more days for the offer. I have to choose these days with the help of checkboxes. I have two class one is offer other is days.

My class offer :

```
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public double price{ get; set; }

    public List<Days> days {get; set; }
```

My class days :

```
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Select { get; set; }
```

It's my controller :

```
public ActionResult AddOffer()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is that I can not add the checkboxes. I try this :

```
public ActionResult AddOffer()
    {
        Days days= new Jours();
        days.Id= 1;
        days.Name= "Monday";
        days.Select = false;
        return View(days);
    }
```

It's not work because it's say "Argument type Days is not assignable to model type Offer. Indeed, in my view I use @model Project.Models.Offer. But I need it. So I don't know how add checkbox with this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow this example using Data Annotations attribute:

ViewModel class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcRequiredCheckbox
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Terms and Conditions")]
        [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You gotta tick the box!")]
        public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
namespace MvcRequiredCheckbox
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(viewModel);
            }

            return Content("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcRequiredCheckbox.SampleViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ASP.NET MVC - Required Checkbox with Data Annotations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .field-validation-error {
            color: #ff0000;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>ASP.NET MVC - Required Checkbox with Data Annotations</h1>

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions) 
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TermsAndConditions)
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Submit</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="credits text-center">
      <p>
          <a href="http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2013/10/16/ASPNET-MVC-Required-Checkbox-with-Data-Annotations.aspx">ASP.NET MVC - Required Checkbox with Data Annotations</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="http://jasonwatmore.com">JasonWatmore.com</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <script>
        // extend jquery range validator to work for required checkboxes
        var defaultRangeValidator = $.validator.methods.range;
        $.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
            if(element.type === 'checkbox') {
                // if it's a checkbox return true if it is checked
                return element.checked;
            } else {
                // otherwise run the default validation function
                return defaultRangeValidator.call(this, value, element, param);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

From: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbPh0X